# Express.js function to redirect http to https not working

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, express, https

I'm trying to redirect all http requests to https in an Express app, and have the following code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('validPathToSSLKey'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('validPathToSSLCertBundles')
}
///...
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next){
   if (!req.secure){
      return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
   }
   next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
module.exports(app);
```

Currently, the SSL works fine, but the only route that doesn't get redirected to https is when the url is prefaced by 'http' (as in http://domain.com). I've tried implementing a few snippets provided by Stack Overflow posts, some of which suggest altering the IP tables, but I hope to implement something that redirects without having to deal with the firewall. Any ideas?

Comment: I tested your code and it is working for me! Do you see any errors? What is not working?

Comment: The website is for a domain called uncommonhacks.com. On my browser (Chrome), if I enter uncommonhacks.com, it redirects to https. Likewise for https://uncommonhacks.com and www.uncommonhacks.com. However, when I enter http://www.uncommonhacks.com, it directs only to www.uncommonhacks.com without the certification, which is what the above implementation was trying to resolve.